# React Navigation: Screen not clickable after modal (EDIT: it's a bug)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm using a transparent modal, but whenever I exit the modal (no matter if I go back or to another page) I can't click anything on the screen anymore. This only happens when I set `presentation: 'transparentModal'`.

I first thought it's a bug, but I can't find any other people with this issue, so I guess I'm doing something wrong. Do you see anything stupid I'm overlooking?

Navigator Screen:

```
<Screen
  name="Modal"
  component={Modal}
  options={{
    headerShown: false,
    cardStyle: {backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)'},
    cardOverlayEnabled: true,
    presentation: 'transparentModal',
  }}
/>
```

Component:

```
const Modal = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="go back" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    maxHeight: (height * 2) / 3,
    backgroundColor: '#30444E',
    borderRadius: 16,
    marginHorizontal: 24,
    marginTop: height * 0.1,
    padding: 24,
  },
});
```

EDIT: Nevermind, I'm apparently blind. Seems to be a library [issue](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/10037) I just didn't look properly. But besides that, if somebody has a clever workaround, I'd appreciate the input.

Answer (score 0):

I hope all well with you.

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal for this.